# Stackdriver Debug shows "multiple modules matching" error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to live debug a Python Google App Engine Standard application in Stackdriver Debug console.  When I click on a deployed file (main.py) and the line where I want it to break, I get an error message stating "Multiple modules matching" and lists a couple files with the same name.

This is a new deployed version with that filename being unique in my project.  I wouldn't expect it to see multiples of the same filename.  Because of that error, I am unable to debug the deployed app.

Comment: Does your app have multiple services/modules?

Comment: It just has the one service module (default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger loops through all the loaded Python modules in the project and may find a file with the same name.  When multiple files are listed, copy and paste the full path to the file you are wanting to debug.

Example: `apps/[PROJECT]/[VERSION.UNIQUE_ID]/myfile.py:[LINE_NUMBER]`

You can copy the full path from the file listed in the error message.

Comment: You mean because it found another file called `main.py` in some other module?

Comment: Yes, it also found "runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/main.py" although that is not part of my application code.  So, if I use the full path to my "main.py" file - it works.  I don't believe I had to do this before - so might be a bug on the debugger.